# Implement Binary Tree Iterator search Method, which is travel in order through Tree in Java

Tags: java, iterator, inorder

I have to implement a custom Iterator for a Binary Tree, which "next method" is sorting the binary tree. I'm not allowed to use any java.util package, so I can't use a stack for that.

```
@Override
    public T next() {
        T result = node.data;
        if (node.rightChild != null) {
            node = smallest(node.rightChild);
        } else {
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return result;
    }



    private Nodes<T> smallest(Nodes<T> n) {
        if (n.leftChild != null) {
            return smallest(n.leftChild);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
```

At the moment, he just Iterate until there is no more rightChild. Can you please help me, finishing the "next method"?

**Thanks to all of you**

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing this is my solution, which is working fine. If somebody needs the full Code just ask

```
 @Override
    public T next() {
        T result = node.data;
        if (node.rightChild != null) {
            node = smallest(node.rightChild);
        } else {
            while (node.parent != null && node != node.parent.leftChild){
                node = node.parent;
            }
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return result;
    }


    private Nodes<T> smallest(Nodes<T> n) {
        if (n.leftChild != null) {
            return smallest(n.leftChild);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
```